# Using Google Cloud Endpoint, why is there a static/proxy.html used for certain requests?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

We're using a Google Cloud Java Endpoint with a Javascript Client and we've noticed that in some cases, requests, originating from IE11, seem to be go thru the cloud endpoint static proxy (project.appspot.com/_ah/api/static/proxy.html) -- as the HTTP referrer (referer).

Why?

Furthermore, when those requests fail, they do with the follow error:

response: {
 status: 0
 statusText: No status text available
 body: {"error":{"code":-1,"message":"A network error occurred, and the request could not be completed."}}
}

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The proxy.html is used as an alternate way of making cross domain requests. If the request fails when coming from API Explorer (`project.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`) or it works in other browsers, this is likely a bug and you'll want to file a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Component=Endpoints). I would double check that those errors aren't coming from your API backend.